# Graphql for aggregation using Spring

Tags: graphql, graphql-java

My application has REST API built and we are planning to use GraphQL. Would like to know if there is any documentation or any online reference briefing the integration of GraphQL Apollo with Spring on server side. Any help please.

Answer (score 1):

Your question way too broad to be answered. Any GraphQL client will work with any GraphQL server, and the server can be implemented with any framework stack, as GraphQL is only the API layer.

For a minimal (but pretty complete) Spring Boot example with graphql-java, using [graphql-spqr](https://github.com/leangen/graphql-spqr), see https://github.com/leangen/graphql-spqr-samples

In short, you create a normal controller, where you create the GraphQL schema and initialize the runtime, and expose an endpoint to receive queries.

```
@RestController
public class GraphQLSampleController {

    private final GraphQL graphQL;

    @Autowired
    public GraphQlSampleController(/*Inject the services needed*/) {

        GraphQLSchema schema = ...; //create the schema
        graphQL = GraphQL.newGraphQL(schemaFromAnnotated).build();
    }

    //Expose an endpoint for queries
    @PostMapping(value = "/graphql", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    public Object endpoint(@RequestBody Map<String, Object> request) {
        ExecutionResult executionResult = graphQL.execute((String) request.get("query"));

        return executionResult;
    }
}
```

This is the bare minimum. For a complete tutorial, using graphql-java-tools but without Spring, check out [the Java track on HowToGraphQL](https://www.howtographql.com/graphql-java/0-introduction/).

Comment: Thanks a ton. I don't have any idea when i posted this question, but later on i surfed some stuff over internet and got some basic knowledge. You response is really useful. I have heard of apollo-data graphql server and was recommended today to start the analysis. But we have REST api's built with Spring and Jersey combination. Does apollo-data comes with any such tool or plugin which will convert the queries from client and provide me a way to talk to existing code or API's. Otherwise should i have to completely rewrite my existing API or code. Please throw some pointers which will help.

Comment: @user2585494 As I said, GraphQL is only an API layer, so it can reuse anything you already have. You could have a GraphQL server in JavaScript calling your REST endpoints, or a GraphQL server in Java directly calling the same methods that are behind REST. Btw, if I helped you, why not accept and upvote the answer?